# sharedPreference or onSaveInstanceState on an EditText/TextView result

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, savestate

I have a little test project below. All I want to do is save the EditText numbers entered and TextView result (thing1, thing2, result) . What's best? onSaveInstanceState, sharedPreference, or something different like SQLite?

I've frustratingly tried the first two (for probably embarrassingly too long), but couldn't figure it out. Could someone please help by adding it to the code below?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



EditText thing1;
EditText thing2;
TextView result;

double n1=0;
double n2=0;
double total=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final Button divideButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divideButton);
    divideButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            thing1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thing1);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(thing1.getText().toString())) {
                n1 = 0;}
            else {
                 n1= Double.parseDouble(thing1.getText().toString());
            }

            thing2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thing2);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(thing2.getText().toString())) {
                n2 = 0;}
            else {
                n2 = Double.parseDouble(thing2.getText().toString());
            }

            if (n2 !=0){

             total = (n1 / n2);}


            final double total =  ((double)n1/(double)n2);

            final TextView result= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

            String foo = String.format("%.2f", total);
            result.setText(foo);


        }

    });


    final Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            thing1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thing1);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(thing1.getText().toString())) {
                n1 = 0;}
            else {
                n1= Double.parseDouble(thing1.getText().toString());
            }

            thing2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thing2);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(thing2.getText().toString())) {
                n2 = 0;}
            else {
                n2 = Double.parseDouble(thing2.getText().toString());
            }


            final double total =  (n1+n2);

            final TextView result= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

            String foo = String.format("%.2f", total);
            result.setText(foo);


        }

    });


    final Button subtractButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtractButton);
    subtractButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            thing1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thing1);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(thing1.getText().toString())) {
                n1 = 0;}
            else {
                n1= Double.parseDouble(thing1.getText().toString());
            }

            thing2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thing2);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(thing2.getText().toString())) {
                n2 = 0;}
            else {
                n2 = Double.parseDouble(thing2.getText().toString());
            }




            final double total =  (n1-n2);

            final TextView result= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

            String foo = String.format("%.2f", total);
            result.setText(foo);


        }

    });


    final Button multiplyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiplyButton);
    multiplyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            thing1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thing1);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(thing1.getText().toString())) {
                n1 = 0;}
            else {
                n1= Double.parseDouble(thing1.getText().toString());
            }

            thing2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thing2);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(thing2.getText().toString())) {
                n2 = 0;}
            else {
                n2 = Double.parseDouble(thing2.getText().toString());
            }


            final double total =  (n1*n2);

            final TextView result= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

            String foo = String.format("%.2f", total);
            result.setText(foo);



        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want to save it for a long time or just as long as the app is open?

Comment: Long enough so it remembers what you put in if you would open and close the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you will just use the values later like when you open your application, you
can use the SharedPreferences. Based on your code above you can add the code below
to save your EditText data to SharedPreferences and restore it later.

To save your EditText value:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("ProjectName", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("thing1", thing1.getText.toString());    
editor.commit();
```

To get the value from SharedPreferences you can do this in your onCreate function:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("ProjectName", MODE_PRIVATE);
String sValue = sharedPreferences.getString("thing1", "default");
thing1.setText( sValue );
```